# Rails 4 - Validate Unique with Condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4

I am trying to validate a request to disallow a user from requesting the same schedule he requested before, but there may be times when the user requested a schedule that then gets canceled, but then reopened (schedule.state_id changes), so they should be able to re-request the same schedule.

How can I approach this?

```
Request Model
belongs_to :user, :schedule

validates :schedule_id, uniqueness {scope: :user_id, message: "this user has already requested this class"}, presence: true
```

Comment: Check out this post on conditional validation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533891/rails-validates-if

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a shot.  Appreciate your time.